# Регулярные выражения в nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, php-nginx, nginx-faq

Нужно настроить `server_name` в nginx.conf на прием поддомена из CNAME записи. 
Имя поддомена может содержать как буквы, так и цифры.
Попробовал `^(www\.)?([a-z0-9]*\.)?(site\.ru)`
Такая запись не проходит при попытке зайти на `track.site.ru` выходит окно nginx, а при переходе с помощью `https://track.site.ru` переходит на нужный домен, но пишет, что соединение не защищено.

Как правильно записать условие для nginx конфига?

Для чего нужен символ `~` перед регулярным выражением в nginx?

Comment: `server_name *.site.ru`

Comment: `server_name www.example.com ~^\w+\.site\.ru$;`

Comment: Судя по описанию, у вас отдельные блоки для `http` и `https` и вы поменяли конфиг только в `https`. А что бы браузеры не ругались на сертификат, вам нужен сертификат валидный для поддоменов.